# Result type Element dos not match expected type Swift2

Tags: xcode, swift2

I get the following error when I try to run my code. Was working before then I upgrade Xcode and got Xcode Beta version 7.0 for IOS9. Asked me to convert code to swift 2 Syntax now its giving me error. Snippet of my code below.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var mapView:MKMapView!

var restaurant:Restaurant!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self

    // Convert address to coordinate and annotate it on map
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(restaurant.location, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if placemarks != nil && placemarks!.count > 0 {
            let placemark = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark

            // Add Annotation
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = self.restaurant.name
            annotation.subtitle = self.restaurant.type
            annotation.coordinate = placemark.location.coordinate

            self.mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
            self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)

        }

    })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 7.0 placemarks array is no longer [AnyObject]? but is now [CLLocation]?. There is no need to cast the array. Add guard statements to your swift code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var mapView:MKMapView!

var restaurant:Restaurant!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self

    // Convert address to coordinate and annotate it on map
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {

        let location = locations.last


        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!) { placemarks, error in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks else { print(error); return; }
            guard let placemark = placemarks.first else { return; }

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = self.restaurant.name
            annotation.subtitle = self.restaurant.type
            annotation.coordinate = placemark.location!.coordinate

            self.mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
            self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
        }

    }
}
```